# How to start and stop the main thread from outside the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i want to start or stop the main thread  from child thread ...

is it possible  ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {

        static int threadid;
        static async void create()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("from child");
            Thread mainthread = new Thread();//throws error
            mainthread.ManagedThreadId = threadid;//throws error here  
           if (mainthread.ThreadState==System.Threading.ThreadState.Suspended)
            mainthread.Resume();

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadStart creat_ = new ThreadStart(create);
            Thread create_thread = new Thread(creat_);
            create_thread.Start();
             threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend();
            create_thread.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

here in the above code create_thread is the child thread and i want to stop start/resume the main thread from the create_thread .

Comment: Golly why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

But the question is why would you want to do this?  This gives you zero chance to cleanup any files or save data before quitting.

Comment: If the other thread that is created is not a background thread, the process won't be terminated when the main thread is aborted. It's still not a good idea to do it, though.

Comment: Ending the process will kill the other threads regardless if they are foreground or background.

Comment: i just want to get the main thread from suspended state to  running state  again from the child thread .